# Rails ORM, can it cope with a compound Primary key of two foreign keys referencing the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

*Edited 30th, 03:16, to show improved migration and model*

I have a table of elements that can each be connected to many other elements.  Is it possible to do this in Rails' migrations and models?  (the following is it implemented in SQL)

*Table of Elements:* has an integer id primary key field, along with others.

*Table of Inter Element Links:*

```
CREATE TABLE inter_element_links
(
  element1_id integer NOT NULL,
  element2_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT inter_element_links_pkey PRIMARY KEY (element1_id, element2_id),
  CONSTRAINT foreign_key_on_id1 FOREIGN KEY (element1_id)
      REFERENCES elements (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT foreign_key_on_id2 FOREIGN KEY (element2_id)
      REFERENCES elements (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

And this query returns all elements linked to a particular element by its id, e.g. 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM elements
INNER JOIN inter_element_links ON (elements.id = inter_element_links.element1_id
  OR elements.id = inter_element_links.element2_id)
WHERE (inter_element_links.element1_id = 3 OR inter_element_links.element2_id = 3)
AND elements.id <> 3
```

**This works in Postgres and I'd like to translate into Rails but am struggling to find a solution for Rails... is what I'm doing stupid or is it just not that common?**

So far I have the migration ([which has a fake compound primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226321/fake-a-composite-primary-key-rails) and no foreign keys referencing elements.id):

```
class CreateInterElementLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :inter_element_links, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :element1_id, :null => false
      t.integer :element2_id, :null => false
    end
    add_index :inter_element_links, [:element1_id, :element2_id], :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :inter_element_links, [:element1_id, :element2_id]
    drop_table :inter_element_links
  end
end
```

And have the following models:

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :inter_element_links1, :foreign_key => 'element1_id', :class_name => 'InterElementLink', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :inter_element_links2, :foreign_key => 'element2_id', :class_name => 'InterElementLink', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :elements1, :through => :inter_element_links1
  has_many :elements2, :through => :inter_element_links2

  def inter_element_links  ## Unless there's a more elegant rails solution, I will try to extend ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociation, so things like:  an_element.destroy, will destroy the entry in the inter_element_links table, and calls to an_element.elements will work.
    inter_element_links1 + inter_element_links2
  end

  def elements
    elements1 + elements2
  end
end

class InterElementLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_keys :element1_id, :element2_id   ## I have included the 'composite_primary_keys', '=3.1.0' gem
  belongs_to :element
end
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

---

I've found a few things over the last 24 hours that seem to be close but haven't got me all the way yet:

- Similar problem was [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/d049c215aac44135/20339bd701bb7806?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=has_two&pli=1#) but I haven't been able to track down the proposed plugin and it doesn't help for the migrations side of things.
- I have [used this plugin](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/) to successfully get a Rails imitation Primary key on InterElementLink so if there's one where element1_id = 3 and element2_id = 5, a call to InterElementLink.find(3,5) works, but obviously InterElementLink.find(5,3) doesn't work... and I/ActiveRecord will need it to.
- I understand ORMs including ActiveRecord don't support foreign keys, [see a good discussion about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928425/why-do-rails-migrations-define-foreign-keys-in-the-application-but-not-in-the-dat) ([though I understand you can use this plug in](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner)).  [I tried this to make a primary key](http://errtheblog.com/posts/14-composite-migrations), but that failed.

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is. What exactly do you want to know?